# Mark auto-replied emails a certain label during out of work hours

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail

Currently I am using the following code, which works fine but I wonder if it is possible that I can mark emails which were auto-replied by a specific label, so that I can check when I return to work?

```
  function autoReply() {
  var interval = 5;    //  if the script runs every 5 minutes; change otherwise
  var date = new Date();
  var day = date.getDay();
  var hour = date.getHours();
  if ([4,5,6,0].indexOf(day) > -1 || (day == 1 && hour < 9) || (day == 3 && hour >= 17)) {
    var timeFrom = Math.floor(date.valueOf()/1000) - 60 * interval;
    var threads = GmailApp.search('is:inbox after:' + timeFrom);
    var files = DriveApp.getRootFolder().getFilesByName('autoreply.html');
    var htmlbody;
    while (files.hasNext()) {
      var file = files.next();
      htmlbody = file.getBlob().getDataAsString('utf8');      
    }
    for (var i = 0; i < threads.length; i++) {
      if (threads[i].isUnread()){
      threads[i].reply("", {
          htmlBody: htmlbody
        });
      threads[i].markRead();
      threads[i].markImportant();
      }
    }
  }
}
```

So far, I can only get `threads[i].markImportant`work, but `threads[i].markStarred` or other customised labels won't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### You need to use the method [starMessages(messages)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-app#starmessagesmessages)

Sample:

```js
for (var i = 0; i < threads.length; i++) {
      if (threads[i].isUnread()){
      threads[i].reply("", {
          htmlBody: htmlbody
        });
      GmailApp.starMessages(threads[i].getMessages());
      }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks. I'll have a try. Plus, is it possible to use customised label??

Comment: This is also possible, you need to define `GmailApp.getUserLabelByName(name).addToThread(threads[i])`

Comment: Wow! Thanks for helping a noob again!